# leftBarButtonItem is not show image , but action works

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code :

```
func addBackButton() {
    let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "btn_banner_arrow_right"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector (backButtonClick))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button1
}

@objc func backButtonClick() {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
}
--------------------------------------------------
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.addBackButton()
}
```

The function backButtonClick() is work, but the image not show.

My image like this in "Asset"

[image]

And here is my problem(red circle)

[image]

How should I do to resolve this problem ?

**EDIT:**
The image  file is in "Assets"
[image  file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSLcw.png)
But button1 can't show this image
[can't show this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpzNb.png)

Comment: @matt The image in Asset named "btn_banner_arrow_right"

Comment: @matt I edit this question

Comment: no 1x image, Is it because of this reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your image and assign it to navigation bar button...For best result put your image in 2x position in Assets...This is all...

```
let image = UIImage(named: "btn_banner_arrow_righ")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) //here set image with original rendering mode
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(backButtonClick))
```

this is the result:

[image]